# Why beautiful soup does not return the results in order?

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape IEEE explorer to extract the list of papers and authors. Now the problem is the following code first returns the name of authors and then returns the list of papers but in the webpage the order of content is not like this. I don't know why this happens??

```
import requests
page = requests.get('http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/mostRecentIssue.jsp?punumber=7109453&rowsPerPage=100')

import bs4
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.content)
names = soup.select('.prefNameLink , .art-abs-url span')

for index, name in enumerate(names):
    print name.text.strip()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using [a group of selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#grouping) like `.prefNameLink, .art-abs-url span`, the order of the selected elements is not guaranteed to match the order in which they appear in the document. As demonstrated in your example, all the `.prefNameLink` elements are selected first *then* the entire document is parsed again and all the `.art-abs-url span` elements are selected.

The simplest approach to resolve this would be to iterate over each of the container elements *then* retrieve each corresponding name within that container.

In doing so, the document is only parsed once and the order is maintained for each group:

```
for container in soup.select('.results > li'):
    for name in container.select('.prefNameLink, .art-abs-url span'):
        print name.text.strip()
```

However, since each paper may have multiple authors, the better approach would be to iterate over each author for each paper.

In doing so, the order will be maintained within each container as well:

```
for container in soup.select('.results > li'):
    for paper in container.select('.art-abs-url span'):
        print paper.text.strip()

        for author in container.select('.prefNameLink'):
            print author.text.strip()
```